# Visual Basic 2010 Console Writing Out

Tags: .net, vb.net, console, stdout

I am working with a console application for VB 10.

How can I replace data that I have already written with:

```
Console.Write
```

Or how can I write on a specific point: e.g. 100 lines, 100 chars left

In the same way that a program such as wget has a loading bar that does not keep getting replaced every time progress is increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the console [CursorTop and CursorLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) will do what you want. As an example this will count both the upper left and lower right corners of the console window

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        For x = 0 To 10000
            Console.CursorTop = 0
            Console.CursorLeft = 0
            Console.Write(10000 - x)
            Console.CursorLeft = 75
            Console.CursorTop = 24
            Console.Write(x)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```